# how to set blank space when records is not into data base

Tags: php, html, mysql

i am created html form ,when i click on submit button i get records from data base,but if the data is not in to the data base its print http://bukkyolu.com/mp3/upload/ that not come form database its just static value that i am print in statement bellow  http://bukkyolu.com/mp3/upload/".$row['2']."'> ,if the .$row['2'].is not in to database i want empty space not http://bukkyolu.com/mp3/upload/

```
<?php
$category=$_POST["category"];
$month=$_POST["month"];

$mysql_hostname = "localhost";
$mysql_user = "root";
$mysql_password = "";
$mysql_database = "bukkyolu_mp3";
$bd = mysql_connect($mysql_hostname, $mysql_user, $mysql_password)
or die("Opps some thing went wrong");
mysql_select_db($mysql_database, $bd) or die("Opps some thing went wrong");

    $query  = "SELECT title,Amp3,Bmp3,Cmp3 FROM mp3_data WHERE`category` = '$category' and `month` = '$month' ";
$result1 = mysql_query($query);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result1);
//echo $row['s_id'];

 echo "<table border='1' align='center' >";

while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result1)){
 // echo "<td><a href='#' onclick='someFunction()'>" .$row['0']. "</a> </td>";
   echo "<tr><th>Title:</th><td>".$row['0']."</td></tr>";  
 echo "<tr><th>African:</th><td><a href 'http://bukkyolu.com/mp3/upload/".$row['1']."'>http://bukkyolu.com/mp3/upload/".$row['0']."</a></td></tr>";
 echo "<tr><th>British:</th><td><a href 'http://bukkyolu.com/mp3/upload/".$row['2']."'>http://bukkyolu.com/mp3/upload/".$row['0']."</a></td></tr>";
 echo "<tr><th>Caribbean:</th><td><a href 'http://bukkyolu.com/mp3/upload/".$row['3']."'>http://bukkyolu.com/mp3/upload/".$row['3']."</a></td></tr>";
  echo "<tr></tr>";
  echo "<tr></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
}
?>
```

Comment: when creating your combo options check the value of the posted value and mark the entry as selected ie if($_POST['month']=='january') echo ' selected="selected"';

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i didn't see combo1 and combo2 in your code... however since you have html and php in the same page..its better to check for post before doing mysqlquery..

```
<?php
 if(isset($_POST){
     $category=$_POST["category"];
     $month=$_POST["month"];

     $mysql_hostname = "localhost";
     ...... //rest of your code
 }
```

to select the selected value..

```
<select name="category">        
  <option <?php echo ( isset($_POST) && ($_POST['category'] =="animals"))? "selected='selected'":"" ?> value="animals">Animals</option>
  <option <?php echo ( isset($_POST) && ($_POST['category'] =="biblical"))? "selected='selected'":"" ?> value="biblical">Biblical</option>
  <option <?php echo ( isset($_POST) && ($_POST['category'] =="fables"))? "selected='selected'":"" ?> value="fables">Fables</option>
  <option <?php echo ( isset($_POST) && ($_POST['category'] =="fairy tales"))? "selected='selected'":"" ?> value="fairy tales">Fairy Tales</option>
  <option <?php echo ( isset($_POST) && ($_POST['category'] =="historical"))? "selected='selected'":"" ?> value="historical">Historical</option>
 </select>
```

same for other combo

Comment: thank you bipen,i have another one question when i select mont=feb an category=history i am getting all of this record but not getting values of on page in combo box which ever i am selected i am getting 1st value of both,how can i solve this problem

Comment: yes this works ,but 1st time i am call the page i am getting all combo box name like this

Comment: not worked i am getting error like this notice:undefined index category on catogery combo box and  notice:undefined index month on month combo box

Answer (score 0):

That's just a notice, it's not a fatal error. Your page should still run regardless. It simply means that the variables combo1 and combo2 weren't initalized anywhere in your source code yet you're using them somewhere. In order to make sure it doesn't siplay that error put this line of code at the top of your page.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
```

Comment: thank you user1928545,i have another one question when i select mont=feb an category=history i am getting all of this record but not getting values of on page in combo box which ever i am selected i am getting 1st value of both,how can i solve this problem

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you're saying. Ask it in another question and I'll check it out.

Comment: when i click submit button i want to get that value which ever i am selected,not 1st values of both combo box.